# How can I index my entire disk in ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, search

I would like to index my entire disk for quick search.  I tried Tracker, but it doesn't let me add "/" as a recursively indexed directory.  How can I do this?

Comment: This question is not related to programming. So it would be more appropriate at http://askubuntu.com/ , or http://serverfault.com/ , or http://superuser.com/ .

Answer (score 8):

`updatedb` / `locate` is certainly a good choice, if you're looking to index file names.  [See/upvote cYrus's answer.](https://superuser.com/questions/231896/how-can-i-index-my-entire-disk-in-ubuntu/231905#231905)

However, another option is to simply use `find` to list the names of all files on your hard drive, and put them in a file:

```
sudo find / > files.list
```

Later on, you can look for files with `grep`:

```
grep 'myfavoritesong' files.list
```

Although this looks pretty lame, it actually tends to be fast in practice, even when you have a lot of files.

Of course, that hardly does anything better than `locate`.  However, it is a quick and easy way to index external hard drives.

Taking it further, you may want to hash all the files on your hard drive:

```
sudo find / -type f -exec sha256sum {} \; > files.sha256
```

This will probably take a long time.

What it does for you is it gives you a way to locate identical files.  Say you find a huge `.iso` file on your computer:

```
$ sha256sum huge.iso
2cf24dba5fb0a30e26e83b2ac5b9e29e1b161e5c1fa7425e73043362938b9824  huge.iso
```

You have a feeling that the same file exists somewhere else on your hard drive, and you want to delete one of them to save space.  You can grep through the list of hashes to find it:

```
$ grep 2cf24dba5fb0a30e26e83b2ac5b9e29e1b161e5c1fa7425e73043362938b9824 files.sha256
2cf24dba5fb0a30e26e83b2ac5b9e29e1b161e5c1fa7425e73043362938b9824  huge.iso
2cf24dba5fb0a30e26e83b2ac5b9e29e1b161e5c1fa7425e73043362938b9824  archive/path/to/other/huge.iso
```

Comment: +1: It's an interesting solution. A little bit tricky and maybe not so fast, but surely "didactical"; IMO useful.

Answer (score 3):

It should already be indexed regularly with scheduled executions of `updatedb` that's used by `locate`. For more info refer to the `man` of these two programs.

**Note:** I'm talking about file names only.